# Setup different apps on routes of single domain with Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have a situation where we need to run a website at example.com on webflow. Currently we have a webapp running at app.example.com, but for SEO purposes we would like to move it to example.com/app. We're using AWS Route 53 as a DNS provider.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible with Route53, since that is a Domain Name Service (DNS), not a path routing service. This is one of the features of CloudFront though.